# How do I create and remove a directory with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, shell, sh

I need C# methods are that provides mkdir & rm commands for a file system. Is there any Library?

Comment: You are using C# with .Net (aka .Net Core) but you can't use [`Directory.CreateDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.createdirectory?view=net-7.0)?

Comment: I didnt know it thanks

Comment: Ah. The .Net runtime abstracts the file system for you. See the [System.IO.Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory?view=net-7.0) and [System.IO.File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=net-7.0) classes.

Comment: This is a classic example of the [X/Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Your actual question should have been "How do I create and remove a directory with C#?", which you would have found much better results on internet searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cross-platform .Net (formerly .Net Core) library abstracts many of the OS differences including the filesystem.

See the [`System.IO` namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io?view=net-7.0) and specifically the [`Directory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory?view=net-7.0), [`DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=net-7.0), [`File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=net-7.0), and [`FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=net-7.0) classes.